# Using Asset_path tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to using asset_path in a javascript file but I'm getting a error say the file was not found.
The file is under `app/assets/images/Elidium/items/`.

```
new Item(' <%= asset_path '/Elidiun/items/ancienp_hair_olive.png' %>'),
```

Comment: I'll take a guess that you have a typo in your path, that it should be "ancien**t**", not "ancien**p**"

Comment: @Deefour It is spelled correctly. I'm using file found [here](https://github.com/Hydrotoast/Avaku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= asset_path '/Elidiun/items/ancienp_hair_olive.png' %>
```

should be

```
<%= asset_path 'Elidiun/items/ancienp_hair_olive.png' %>
```

I believe the former will mess with the relative URL required to map to `/assets/...`